# Find max of all trees resulting from single edge removal in generic tree in linear time

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given a generic tree with $n$ weighted nodes, there are $n-1$ edges. Removing any of the edges will partition the tree into two distinct trees, hence we can construct $2(n-1)$ possible trees in this way. Is there a way to find the node with the maximum value in each of these resulting trees, that is all the $2(n-1)$ values in $O(n$) time?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that nodes have a field maxvalue that gives the value of the largest node of the subtree in which it is the root. Now we can define a function as follows:

```
foo(tree t):
    //Lets assume t has fields t.maxvalue and t.secondmaxvalue
    t.maxvalue=valueof(t)
    for all children tchild of t do:
        temp=foo(tchild)
        if(temp>t.maxvalue):
            t.maxvalue=temp
        else if(temp>t.secondmaxvalue):
            t.secondmaxvalue=temp
        //the idea is that t.maxvalue will contain the value of the largest child of t and t.secondmaxvalue will contain the value of the second largest child of t.
    return t.maxvalue
```

We define other function as follows (assume `root` is the root of the entire tree):

```
foo2(tree t):
    for all children tchild of t do:
        if(t.maxvalue==root.maxvalue):
            print("if we disconnect the tree at (t,tchild) then we will get two trees with max node values as root.maxvalue and root.secondmaxvalue")
        else:
            print("if we disconnect the tree at (t,tchild) then we will get two trees with max nodes values as t.maxvalue and root.maxvalue")
```

Now we first call `foo(root)` and then `foo2(root)`. Both the two functions traverse each node exactly once and hence have linear time.

Comment: I am a bit confused about sorting the vertices such that $(v_{i-1}, v_i) \in E$. I see how it can work for 1-ary trees (i.e. linked lists), but for a $n$-ary tree with $n > 1$ we might have edges outgoing to the same vertex. How would we for example sort the vertices of a tree consisting of four vertices, where one vertex is the root and the rest are its direct children?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: @avasuilia  Thanks for trying writing an answer. Using meaningless names like `foo` and `foo2` is just a no-no when you are writing code for others to read. People usually prefer pseudocode to code much more. Pseudocode with or without code is fine. Code without pseudocode is not welcomed here.

Comment: Hey @avasuilia, thank you for trying to help. Unfortunately I do not think this idea works. Consider for example $G=(V,E)$, $V= \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ and $E=\{(v_4,v_2),(v_2,v_1),(v_2,v_3)\}$, where $valueof(v_i)=i$. Then your algorithm will compute 3 and 1 as the resulting tree maximums when removing $(v_1,v_2)$, while the correct answer is 1 and 4. In other words, your algorithm does not consider the maximum in the direction of the parent node. I can see how this can be fixed by doing a DFS at every node, but then we get a $O(n^2)$ complexity. Am I perhaps missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Fix an arbitrary `root` of your tree. Then perform a DFS where you compute for each node, what is the maximum value on its subtree (including itself):

```
function max_value_on_subtree(node, parent = NIL):
    node.max_value = node.value
    
    for neighbor in node.neighbors:
        if neighbor == parent:
            continue

        subtree_max_value = max_value_on_subtree(neighbor, node)
        node.max_value = max(node.max_value, subtree_max_value)
    
# Call the function from the `root` (an arbitrary node) to populate the tree.
max_value_on_subtree(root)
```

In the next step, we want to compute the max value on the trees on both sides of the edge for every edge.  We will do this in a separate DFS, where we maintain what is the maximum value among all nodes outside of the subtree we are currently looking in the DFS step. Before traversing an edge, we should compute the maximum value outside of the new subtree, which is the current maximum value, or the maximum on the subtrees from the current node we are inspecting other than the subtree we are stepping into. We build a prefix and sufix table with the max values, to make this computation in $O(1)$

```
function iter_max_values(node, parent = NIL, max_complement = -inf):
    """
    node: Is the current node on the DFS
    parent: The previous node. We keep it to avoid traversing from node to parent
    max_complement: The maximum value on the complement of the subtree with root at `node`
    """

    # Store a list with all the children. The parent is a
    # neighbor of the current node, but it is not a child.
    children = []
    for neighbor in node.neighbors:
        if neighbor != parent:
            children.push(neighbor)

    # Compute the maximum value for every prefix and suffix
    num_children = len(children)
    prefix = list(len = num_children)
    suffix = list(len = num_children)

    # For the sake of brevity, assume indexing out index return `-inf`
    for i in [0, num_children - 1]:
        child_max_value = children[i].max_value
        prefix[i] = max(child_max_value, prefix[i - 1])
    
    # Loop backward.
    for i in [num_children - 1, 0]:
        child_max_value = children[i].max_value
        suffix[i] = max(child_max_value, suffix[i + 1])

    # Iterate through every child, and before traversing the edge
    # toward the children compute the new max_complement
    for i in [0, num_children - 1]:

        # Again, for brevity, assume indexing outside of index returns -inf. 
        new_max_complement = max(max_complement,
                                 node.max_value,
                                 prefix[i - 1],
                                 suffix[i + 1])

        # Before traversing the edge, we have the new max values
        # on both subtrees to the side of this edge.
        # A = new_max_complement
        # B = children[i].max_value
        # In this step, you can operate on them.

        iter_max_values(children[i], node, new_max_complement)


iter_max_values(root)
```

Notice each step of the DFS take $O(|children|)$ time (including computing prefix / suffix / new_max_complement) so overall it takes $O(N)$